# Расхождения в расчётах гравитационной модели в программных средах R и STATA

Tags: r, model, статистика

Уважаемые коллеги!

Мы проводил расчёты гравитационной модели в программных средах **R** и **STATA**.

Для расчётов используется типовой пакет glmm в среде R (с параметром `family=quasipoisson`)
и ppml в STATA.

Вызов процедуры расчёта в среде R такой

```
summary(glmm<-glm(formula=exports ~ ln_GDPimporter + ln_GDPexporter + ln_GDPimppc + ln_GDPexppc + ln_Distance + ln_Tariff + ln_ExchangeRate + Contig + Comlang + Colony_CIS + EAEU_CIS + EU_European_Union, family=quasipoisson(link="log"),data=data_pua))
```

Результаты расчётов в среде R следующие:

[image: Результаты расчётов в среде R]

На тех же данных мы провели расчёты в среде STATA.

Вызов процедуры расчёта в среде STATA следующий

```
ppml exports ln_gdpimporter ln_gdpexporter ln_gdpimppc ln_gdpexppc ln_distance ln_tariff ln_exchangerate contig comlang colony_cis eaeu_cis eu_european_union
```

Результаты расчётов в среде STATA  следующие:

[image: Результаты расчётов в среде STATA]

Как видно оценки коэффициентов модели (вторая колонка в таблицах результатов) совпадают как минимум до 4-го знака (!)

Однако, остальные результаты (колонки в таблице результатов, начиная с третьей) в выводах обоих пакетов не совпадают.

Как можно объяснить полученные результаты?

В частности, почему совпадают оценки (вторые столбцы таблиц результатов), но не совпадают стандартные отклонения (Std. Err., третьи столбцы таблиц результатов) ?

Comment: This is stackoverflow for russian users. If you want to ask in english, use [this.](https://stackoverflow.com). P.S. вы вроде русский ученый, как написано в профиле, переведите свой вопрос на русский и используйте теги кода при написании запроса, Сергей С.

Comment: поправил, теперь по-русски

Answer (score 2):

Потому что в R у вас посчитаны просто стандартные ошибки, а в Stata - некие "устойчивые" стандартные ошибки (Robust Std. Err.). Как видно из названий, это разные величины, соответственно совпадать они не обязаны. p-значения и доверительные интервалы, соответственно, тоже отличаются.

Остается узнать, по какому алгоритму Stata вычисляет эти Robust Std. Err. (начинать копать можно [отсюда](https://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s458102.html)). В R с аналогичной целью можно просто глянуть исходники.

Comment: спасибо, это всё я и сам понимаю, собственно говоря "копать" то и не хочется, потому и спрашиваю у тех, кто уже "покопал" :)

Comment: Исходники смотреть - мягко говоря, не самое лучшее предложение в любом случае. Эдак мы и до машинного кода скоро доберёмся :)